# Let's have a treasure hunt!

Tags: riddle, knowledge

What if I told you that I found a treasure, and that I'm willing to share it with you? Of course you'll have to go through an ugly, not even rhyming, riddle... But I know you're quite fond of them, so enjoy this one!

> Make a 88 days round-trip
>   Go North, then West, enter a country
>   Between the sky and the sea, in the white horizon
>   Sum it in France, to the largest city
>   Name of a "pub maiden" (or something like that), go to her fathers' home
>   In their most known body of water
>   Keep only the name, in an obvious code
>   Dash South and point toward the East from California
>   But stop a bit sooner to avoid the cops!
>   Under the anchor, remove the circle and circle 7 times
>   One animal lead to another, through the cosmic clouds
>   Append his french cousin (because we need a key!)
>   Finally remove xbviilps, and get your reward.

**Will you find the treasure?**

Hint 1:

> The riddle is sequential: every line is a step toward the other. As such, teamwork may be useful if you share your findings ;)

Hint 2:

> Since the "sum it in France" line seems problematic : when I talk about a sum, I expect a number. Also, forget Paris.

Hint 3:

> Here are the themes for each line (in the wrong order of course), except for 2 lines being part of the same step, and 2 other lines having two (close) steps (and thus 2 themes): Astronomy, Astronomy, Communications, Cryptography, Cryptography, Geography, Geography, Geography, Music, Language, Physics, Physics, Vexillology, Vexillology
>  Have fun with this!

Comment: So I have to go to myself?

Comment: You'll have to solve the riddle first, and you'll know what to do next ;)

Comment: I added a hint ;)

Comment: I added a third hint

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[I'm making this a Community wiki -- it seems better suited to attacking this puzzle piece by piece, because all edits take part in one place. I've taken some insights from other answers, especially from Joey Dionne's. Consider upvoting them.]

After much hunting, we've found the treasure. It is ...

> ... **Friendship**.

Make a 88 days round-trip

> (Astronomy) **Mercury**'s orbit around the sun is 88 days.
>  (Physics) Mercury is also an element with symbol **Hg**.

Go North, then West, enter a country

> Up and left from **Hg** in the Periodic table of elements is Silver.
>  (Geography) **Argentina** is an artificial name derived from the Latin name o fsilver (La Plata).

Between the sky and the sea, in the white horizon

> (Vexillology) Argentina's flag has a three horizontal stripes: Light blue (sky), white (horizon) and light blue again (sea). In the centre is the **sun** of May.

Sum it in France, to the largest city

> (Cryptography) The A-to-Z sum of **sun** is 54: S (19) + U (21) + N (14)
>  (Geography) In France, the *départements* are numbered. Number 54 is Meurthe-et-Moselle, whose capital and largest city is **Nancy**.

Name of a "pub maiden" (or something like that), go to her fathers' home

> (Music) "**Nancy** the tavern wench" is a song by the Scottish pirate metal band Alestorm, which hails from Perth, **Scotland**.

In their most known body of water

> (Geography) **Scotland**'s most notorious body of water surely is **Loch Ness**.

Keep only the name, in an obvious code

> (Communications) Loch means Lake in Scottish, so the name proper is just **Ness**. I'm not sure it's an "obvious" code, but in Morse, it's `-. . ... ...`, that is a dash followed by eight dots.

Dash South and point toward the East from California

> (Physics) Take the name in Morse as directions in the periodic system of elements: A dash means move down; a dot means move east. Start in "California", CA, that is at Calcium, **Ca**.

But stop a bit sooner to avoid the cops!

> Moving the full 1 south and 8 east would land us as **Pd** (Palladium), but we want to avoid the cops (or in other words, the Police Department, PD), so we stop at Rhodium, **Rh**.

Under the anchor, remove the circle and circle 7 times

> (Vexillology) The state flag of Rhode Island has an anchor surrouned by a circle of thirteen golden stars. But we must remove the circle *under* the anchor. Right under the anchor on a ribbon is the state's motto, HOPE. Remove the O to get HPE and then Caesar-shift seven times to get an animal, namely an **Owl**.

One animal lead to another, through the cosmic clouds

> (Astronomy) The **Owl** nebula is a "cosmic cloud" in the constallation Ursa Major, the Great **Bear**.

Append his french cousin (because we need a key!)

> (Language) The **bear**'s French cousin is probably just its name in French, **ours**.

Finally remove xbviilps, and get your reward.

> (Cryptography) We have an eight-letter key, **bearours**, and an eight-letter ciphertext, `xbviilps`, which we need to "remove". If we decrypt that with Vigenère, which kinda removes the letter codes from each other, we get "edfjgjca".
>
>  These letters are all from the beginning of the alphabet and we can turn them into a number by substituting a with 0, b with 1, ..., j with 9, and we get 43596920. This number can be read as latitude and longitude in degrees and minutes. One of the possibilities is 43° 59' N, 69° 20' W, which leads to a town in Maine called **Friendship**.

Used fields according to Hint 3:

> <s>Astronomy</s> (Mercury)
>  <s>Astronomy</s> (Owl Nebula)
>  <s>Communications</s> (Morse code)
>  <s>Cryptography</s> (AZ sum)
>  <s>Cryptography</s> (Vigenère)
>  <s>Geography</s> (Argentina)
>  <s>Geography</s> (Nancy)
>  <s>Geography</s> (Loch Ness)
>  <s>Music</s> (Alestorm)
>  <s>Language</s> (Bear → Ours)
>  <s>Physics</s> (Mercury, Silver)
>  <s>Physics</s> (Calcium, Rhodium)
>  <s>Vexillology</s> (Sun of May)
>  <s>Vexillology</s> ("Hope")

Comment: You got one step further than @JoeyDionne ! Try to be less specific...

Comment: So just Scotland and Loch Ness? Then convert to Morse (`-. . ... ...`), perhaps add a dash and see which place East of California can be made from that?

Comment: Since it's "In their most known body of water", i'd say it's the Loch Ness Monster and then convert her name to Morse (`-. . ... ... .. .`)

Comment: Yes, that could be. (And I like how the little dots look like Nessie's body poking out from the murky surface of Loch Ness.)

Comment: I think _Dash South and point toward the East from California_ is the other physic theme. California is the **Golden** state so we begin at Gold. Dash is one step south and dot is one east. Unfortunately, we have too many dots and end outside of the table, that's maybe why we need to stop before (_But stop a bit sooner to avoid the cops!_). There's Moscovium an Tennessine that can be good place to stop but I don't know wich one is better

Comment: @JoeyDionne: You mean that dashes and dots are used to indicate a path in the periodic table? That's brilliant. There's also Californium, but you can't go south from it. The Cops could be "Cop"ernicum, which would leave us at Roentgenium. We need to go somewhere where the flag or shield have an anchor, I guess. (By the way, I've made this a community wikiso you can edit in your findings.)

Comment: I never though about Gold(en state) or... Californium ><. But those 2 look like dead ends at least, so... I'm not that much to blame right?

Comment: What about the [Owl Nebula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owl_Nebula), which is next to the Ursa Maior?

Comment: @LinuxBlanket: Yes, that's better, because it makes use of the "cosmic clouds".

Comment: @MOehm so maybe the next animal must be the name of a nebula as well. There are quite some nebulas named after animals ((here)[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_planetary_nebulae]): medusa, stingray, butterfly, cat's eyes, red spider, bug, ant, and there's also a southern owl.

Comment: You're almost there!

Comment: What do you get when removing? Isn't there something odd with what you obtain?

Comment: Hm. I suppose the key bearours is correct. Removing to me suggests to erase letters, but that doesn't seem to work here. If I subtract xbviilps from bearours by subtracting the A1Z26 codes bit by bit, I get −22, 3, −21, 9, 6, 9, 2, 0, which could be "edfjgjca" or "dceifibz", depending on whether I use A0Z15 or A1Z26. Or are we looking for lon/lat coords? Or eve a tinyurl/pastebin code? I'm probably doing the "removing" wrong.

Comment: Using Vigenere, it give us "yfvzwfgk" but still, don't know what to do with that string. Another solution could be that we need to decypher some string (maybe all the answers) with the key "bearours" and then remove the letters "xbviilps" from the result, but I didn't found any reward :/ There is probably something obvious we are not seeing

Comment: I saw one good idea!

Comment: I thought about putting all answers together, but (a) it's not always clear what they are exactly, (b) it would be quite a super construction to fit the hints _and_ the answers to something that can be decoded with just an 8-letter key, and (c).the second but last line is the only one that has the explicit instructon to "append" something. Removing the letters "xbviilps" from something also crossed my mind, and in an early stage I thought that the constellation should be Fox / Vulpecula, because it has an x and a v. Clearly, we're missing somethong obvious.

Comment: The letters in "edfjgjca" are all in the range a-j and coud be converted to numbers, for example to the coords 43.59, 69.20. Nothing there, though, in either quadrant.

Comment: Really? You found no treasure here?

Comment: What do you mean by "here"? There have been so many wild guesses tossed around that I don't know what to think anymore. (For what it's worth, I think bearours is correct, at least.)

Comment: I was talking about your last comment ;)

Comment: In that case, I don't know whether you are poking fun at me or whether you want to encourage me to pursue that angle further. I fear it's the former. I think that looking for longitudes and latitudes isn't all that unreasonable, but I also think that the removal business hasn't been solved yet.

Comment: Coordinates are right, so what is the real treasure?

Comment: Uhm, the coordinates seem to lead to a body of water in a desertified area in Kazakhstan, so I guess that the treasure is "water"...?

Comment: Don't tell us that the treasure was in ourselves all this time, @Keelhaul :D

Comment: Okay, I have it now. The coords are [43°N 59' 69°W 20'](https://www.google.com/maps/@43.9833,-69.333,14z). Talking about metaphorical treasure ...

Comment: Congratulation, [you've got it!](https://i.redditmedia.com/chBm4GhnDSO4e7BRtXBH_fxH3b2qBHi4GejsLvma4Dk.png?fit=crop&crop=faces%2Centropy&arh=2&w=640&s=e6dd120e0b28f18e04ceb6a7004d98e9)

Answer (score 11):

**Partial Answer**

*Make a 88 days round-trip*

> **Mercury**'s year round trip around the sun last 88 days

*Go North, then West, enter a country*

> The element north west of mercury in the periodic table is silver. The country we enter is **Argentina**, because in Italian it means "made of silver, silver colored"

*Between the sky and the sea, in the white horizon*

> The argentinian flag is three horizontal stripes: blue(sea), white (horizon) and blue(sky). Inside the white stripe is a **Sun**

*Sum it in France, to the largest city*

From @MOehm

> To "sum it in France" could mean the A-Z sum of SUN, 54, and reading it as the number of a department, which leads to the city of **Nancy**

*Name of a "pub maiden" (or something like that), go to her fathers' home*

> Nancy, the only girl in the Oliver Twist gang, is a prostitute (loose definition of a "pub maiden"). Her "father", Charles Dickens is English and now we are in **England**

*In their most known body of water*

> The most known english body of water is the **English Channel**.

*Keep only the name, in an obvious code*

> The English Channel is a sea and SEA is the airport code of **Seattle**

*Dash South and point toward the East from California*
*But stop a bit sooner to avoid the cops!*

> From there I guess we head south of Seattle and somewhere in California we go east, stopping before Beverly Hills (cop) so maybe **Bel Air**?

*Under the anchor, remove the circle and circle 7 times*
*One animal lead to another, through the cosmic clouds*
*Append his french cousin (because we need a key!)*
*Finally remove xbviilps, and get your reward.*

Comment: Almost good at the third (stay simple), and then it goes haywire :p

Comment: When I talk about a sum, I expect a number :p. Also, forget Paris ;)

Comment: I don't know, this seems all a bit too loose. Even if an answer for a single step is found, you can't be confident that it is right. For example, there are many elements named after countries, but we get to pick the one where the country is named after the element. (But the directions how to get there from Hg were clear.) To "sum it in France" could mean the A-Z sum of SUN, 54, and reading it as the number of a _département_, which leads to the city of Nancy, which, in turn could be the name of a famous barmaid. But it could just as well be something else entirely. `:(`

Comment: @MOehm this sounds actually very promising! I was thinking that maybe Nancy Sinatra had something to do with it, but it's nothing more than a wild guess...

Comment: Since we search for a name, what @MOeh found sounds very promising indeed!

Comment: @Keelhaul modified and we are no longer in Paris :P Followed the path of MOehm

Comment: Aaaand you failed on "pub maiden" :D, although I must admit that it might be the hardest to find. Our Lord Google may help you, but remember the "or something like that". This is neither stricly "pub" nor "maiden".

Comment: I added a third hint, also, about your second answer, it's worth noting that Netragvan'f anzr pbzrf sebz vg'f (fhccbfrq) fvyire zbhagnvaf (fvyire vf Nt sebz vgf yngva onfr *netraghz*)

Comment: But the idea to use an airport code was good, wasn't it? I ask, because I'm stranded in Estonia right now ... `:)`

Comment: And the airport code put me in a trip for Rome now, but i'm pretty sure i'm lost again because there is no politic theme and I used one :/

Comment: No airport code :)

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Make a 88 days round-trip

> Mercury's year round trip around the sun last 88 days (Credit to Joey Dionne)

Go North, then West, enter a country

> Starting at Mercury (Nevada), heading north puts you the Canadian border, West takes you to Russia

Notes:

> #2 states Go North (by an unspecified amount), so Japan is an option, as is America (Alaska) if you entered Canada while going North.

Answer (score -1):

Snippets of information:

> There was a book called 88 Days to Kandahar: A CIA Diary by Robert L. Grenier.
>
> Kandahar is located in Afghanistan, which is located in the Middle East (could it be a reference to the directions)
>
> There is another book written called White Horizon: The Arctic in the Nineteenth-Century British Imagination
>
> The largest city in France is Paris.
>
> I'm taking things way too literally sighhhhhhhhhh

Comment: Sorry, you're wrong on every step :p

Comment: Yeah I could tell :p @Keelhaul